# VBA Macro - Copy Partial Row from Sheet to New Sheet if Cell Matches Cell on 3rd Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, match, copy-paste, lookup

So I don't know much about coding but I’m learn quick and have made things work in the past by piggybacking off of existing code the others created, but there are too many moving parts with this one for me.

I need some help writing a VBA for an excel spreadsheet that will save me significant amounts of time comparing & aggregating data going forward. The alternative would be to create multiple VLookup & If commands in the worksheets, which you all know leads to instability in the worksheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the spreadsheet layout:

- Worksheet 1 = "3yr"
- Worksheet 2 = "5yr"
- Worksheet 3 = "10yr"
- Worksheet 4 = "15yr"
- Worksheet 5 = "Combined"
- Worksheet 6 = "Eligible Funds"
- Row 1 is the same in all worksheets

  - Cell A2 is a counter cell using =COUNTA(A3:A1048576)

    - There shouldn’t be a break between any of the rows
    - Not sure if this is needed, as I’ve seen code that does this in the macro (if that’s the case I will delete that row)
- Row 2 in Worksheets 1-5 are identical; Cells A2:BF2 are the column headers

  - Worksheet 5 has 5 additional columns from BG:BL
- Worksheet 6 contains the data that Worksheets 1-4 are going to be cross-referenced against
- Worksheet 5 is going to be the target worksheet to copy the data to, beginning on row 3, if there is a match

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Search Column F of Worksheet 6, row-by-row for “WMC Ineligible” or “Ineligible Share Class” and then delete that entire row if either of those texts are found
- Search Column A of Worksheet 6 for a match of the text in Column B of Worksheet 1 (starts at row 3), row-by-row

  - If found, then search the Column B of Worksheet 5 to see if that row already exists

    - If that row doesn’t exist, copy the cells in columns A2:BF2 for that row (from Worksheet 1) to the first blank row in Worksheet 5, input “1” in column BG, “=SUM(BG3:BJ3)” in column BK, and then copy the text in Column D of the row found in Worksheet 6 into Column BL of the new row in Worksheet 5

      - For worksheet 2 it would input “1” in column BH, “=SUM(BG3:BJ3)” in column BK, and then copy the text in Column D of the row found in Worksheet 6 into Column BL of the new row in Worksheet 5
      - For worksheet 3 it would input “1” in column BI “=SUM(BG3:BJ3)” in column BK, and then copy the text in Column D of the row found in Worksheet 6 into Column BL of the new row in Worksheet 5
      - For worksheet 4 it would input “1” in column BJ “=SUM(BG3:BJ3)” in column BK, and then copy the text in Column D of the row found in Worksheet 6 into Column BL of the new row in Worksheet 5
    - If that row exists, then don’t copy the row again, but instead input:

      - “1” in column BH of that row (if searching Worksheet 2)
      - “1” in column BI of that row (if searching Worksheet 3)
      - “1” in column BJ of that row (if searching Worksheet 4)
    - Move to the next row in Worksheet 1 and repeat the search
    - Once the end of Worksheet 1 is reached, move on to Worksheet 2, then Worksheet 3, and finally worksheet 4

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is really more of a specification than a question though.  Why not try writing the code for this, then post back (with your code) when you run into a specific problem we can help you with ?